# Geolocate Custom Post Type on Save

Tags: custom-post-types, google-maps, geo-data, plugin-types

I was wondering what hook i would use to geo-locate a custom post type when it is saved?

I have a Custom post type of Restaurant and I want to geolocate the address using googles api and then save it into another field(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On post save the 'save_post' action is run. You could hook your function that geolocates to that.

Comment: https://github.com/fyaconiello/wp-geo-posts has all of the code for adding the metaboxes for location and the post_save implementation.